# scrolling other UITableview at the same time as another UItableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a quite complicated view. What I basicly have is the following

[image]

You can see I have a `vertical tableview`. In each cell I have a `horizontal tableview`. What I want to do now is when I scroll one `horizontal tableview`, every other horizontal tableview should scroll also.

In my subClass of the vertical tableviewCell I have the following.

```
  for(HorizontalTableCell *cell in mainTable.subviews){
        if([cell isKindOfClass:[HorizontalTableCell class]]){
            for(UITableView *cellTable in cell.subviews){
                if([cellTable isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]){
                    NSLog(@"cell table is table %@",cellTable);
                    [cellTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0) animated:NO];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is not working OK. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the scroll view delegate methods. I'd suggest posting a Notification and then picking it up in the cells like so...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CellScrolledHorizontally" object:self.tableView];
}
```

Then in the horizontal cells you can observe the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(scrolled:) name:@"CellScrolledHorizontally" object:nil];

- (void)scrolled:(NSNotification *)notification 
{ 
    UITableView *notificationTableView = notification.object; 

    if (notificationTableView == self.tableView) 
        return; 

    [self.tableView setContentOffset:notificationTableView.contentOffset]; 
}
```

Alternatively, use a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: In which class should I set the scollViewDidScroll ? in the HorizontalTableviewCell class ?

Comment: All of this should go in the cells that contain the horizontal tableviews. When the table is scrolled horizontally you post a notification to let the other cells know that this has happened. Then the other "horizontal" cells will update their own tableview to the same scroll offset.

Comment: Okay but I got this error: No known instance method for selector postnotificationwithname:object

Comment: I may have spelt it wrong. It will autocomplete when you start typing it. Ah yes, I checked, it's postNotificationName:object:

Comment: And then I do this in my scrolled:(NSNotification *) -->  [self.horizontalTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake([notification.object floatValue], 0) animated:NO];

Comment: Yes, essentially you are just telling the other cells what has happened and passing enough info for them to do the same. You may need to change the code to get it working 100% but you've got the right idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30045/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-fogmeister)

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this logic:

Instead of `Horizontal tableviews` use a `UIScrollView`. Now the base is a `UITableView` on which the `horizontal scrollviews`. Now use `UIScrollview delegate` methods for event handling.

Although this is not the solution but you can look at [EASYTABLEVIEW](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView)